# No caption of followers below my Facebook cover pic

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I am not able to see the list of my followers and the caption of followers is also not present. What should I do to see my followers?

Answer (score 2):

First thing - If you're under 18, you won't be able to allow people to follow you because minors can't share public posts, and you won't see the Followers option in your account settings.

Second thing - Have you tried to view your followers from the **Friends** section of your timeline?
To do this, click Friends under your cover photo, then click the Followers link. If you don't see a Followers link, hover over **More** and select **Followers** from the dropdown menu.

You'll only see followers if you've allowed people to start following you. To adjust your settings to let people follow you, take the steps in this [Help Center FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/201148673283205/?ref=u2u).